# Iterate groups of user in AD and save them in list

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a procedure that retrieves the user node out of AD:

```
public static void ConnectActiveDirectory()
{
    List<string> lstGroups = new List<string>();
    DirectoryEntry entry;
    string user = "username";
    string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.Server"];

    entry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + server);
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    searcher.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" + user;
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("MemberOf");
    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
}
```

The idea is to save all the groups in the list of strings without doing something like:

```
foreach (ResultPropertyValueCollection s in result.Properties.Values)
{
    string groupname = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
    {
        dn = s[i].ToString();
        equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
        commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);

        groupname = dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1);

      lstGroups.Add(groupname);
    }
}
```

Is there any method that I can use in 'DirectorySearcher' Class?

Also, is there any way to delete the first Hashtable? the adspath one from the SearchResult object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parsing the distinguished name by yourself, you can use the `DirectoryEntry` object to ask AD for the display name. For example:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://address");
var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
directorySearcher.Filter = "samaccountname=user";
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
var result = directorySearcher.FindOne();
foreach (var i in result.Properties["memberOf"])
{
    var group = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + i);
    Console.WriteLine(group.Properties["DisplayName"]);
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, you are right, thanks for the input. Will read more about DirectoryEntry class. +1 and marked as answer.